# How to adjust the heap size for application using adoptopenjdk in docker container

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, adoptopenjdk

I'm running hypergraphql in a docker container with the Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
RUN curl https://www.hypergraphql.org/resources/hypergraphql-1.0.3-exe.jar --output hypergraphql-1.0.3-exe.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "hypergraphql-1.0.3-exe.jar", "--config", "/config/config.json"]
```

I think I should adjust the JVM size inside my container in order to prevent JVM from taking all available memory into use https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/.

But I don't have any idea about the default JVM heap size. How can I find it and what could be the optimal value for it ?

Comment: There is no universal "optimal heap size". It highly depends on the particular application and the particular environment. There can be different strategies for choosing the heap size, e.g. set the maximum size you an afford; or find the minimum heap size after GC, and then set Xmx to twice of that value.

Comment: yes, understand. What is the default JVM heap size in adoptopenjdk/openjdk8 ?

Answer (score 1):

The default for "max heap size" is usually 25% of available RAM.
It used to take the *host* memory into account but was later fixed for containers too (the fix was backported to Java 8u191 too: https://merikan.com/2019/04/jvm-in-a-container/#backported-to-java-8)

Usually the easiest option to adjust the default "max heap size" is `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0` - here is an example of changing the default 25% to 60%.

As apangin said, there's no "optimal heap size" - you'll need to experiment with it and see what's suitable for your application. You can try to aggressively downsize "max heap size" to the point where your application is barely usable and then multiple that by a factor of 3-5:

- [Gil Tene - Really Understanding Garbage Collection (QCon SF 2019)](https://vimeo.com/374755640) (start at 56:05)

> Start with big heap and shrink it down until it breaks; then tripple that size and go home

- [How to estimate memory consumption?](https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/how-to-estimate-memory-consumption)

> For the impatient ones – the answer will be to start with the memory equal to approximately 5 x [amount of memory consumed by Live Data] and start the fine-tuning from there.